# How to harmonize two raster of different spatial resolution?

Tags: raster, resolution, resampling, downscaling

To harmonize two raster of different spatial resolution, what is most preferred and scientific to do:

1. To make coarse resolution finer

or

2. To make fine resolution coarser?

The datasets includes:

1. Landsat derived NDVI data at 100 m resolution and
2. Climate datasets on 'annual mean temperature' and 'Annual precipitation' at about 4 km resolution.

Goal: To develop some relationship between NDVI and Climatic variables

Comment: Either could be appropriate, but each has costs associated. There is no one solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of data is it? I would think it depends of what kind it is, how you are going to use it, how you present it (as "the truth" or interpolated), your conclusions based on the data etc.

Comment: The datasets includes:
1. Landsat derived NDVI data at 100 m resolution
2. Climate datasets on 'annual mean temperature' and 'Annual precipitation' at about 4 km resolution.
Goal: To develop some relationship between NDVI and Climatic variables.